# mod_wsgi w/ Apache 2.2 and Python 2.7 installation issues. Miniconda as well

Tags: apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, centos6, conda

This problem has eluded me thus far. I have a Centos 6.7 machine running Apache 2.2 with Python 2.7 installed at `/opt/home/user/miniconda2/envs/myenv/lib`. Python 2.6 is obviously also installed on this system at `/usr/bin/python`. At first I installed mod_wsgi with pip and copied the created *.so Apache module to my modules folder. From my perspective it was created with 2.7 but I could not get the stupid `ImportError: package site not found` or whatever to go away. I uninstalled mod_wsgi and compiled and installed from source 4.22. I put the folder into my `/home/user/` directory and started my installation process.

However easy I expected the fine-tuning available to `configure` to be, it quickly became apparent it was anything but. My first hurdle I surpassed, but my second has continued to stump me. After running configure:

`./configure  --with-python=/opt/home/user/miniconda2/envs/myenv/bin/python LD_RUN_PATH=/opt/home/user/miniconda2/envs/myenv/lib`

```
(myenv)[user@machine2 mod_wsgi-4.4.21]$ ldd /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x002a1000)
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => not found
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00164000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00c1f000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0x00c2d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x007cf000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x002a2000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00bcc000)
```

I think we all know that this means the shared library was not found. But I can see it in the directory!
`pwd = /opt/home/user/miniconda2/envs/myenv/lib`

```
[user@machine2 lib]$ ls -l
total 20264
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user    4096 Mar 21 13:46 engines
-rw-rw-r--  2 user user 3066000 Mar  1 12:23 libcrypto.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      18 Mar 21 13:46 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-rwxrwxr-x  1 user user 1945963 Mar 21 13:46 libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r--  3 user user  104318 Jan  3  2014 libhistory.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      15 Mar 21 13:46 libhistory.so -> libhistory.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      17 Mar 21 13:46 libhistory.so.6 -> libhistory.so.6.2
-rwxr-xr-x  3 user user   78845 Jan  3  2014 libhistory.so.6.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      19 Mar 21 13:47 libpython2.7.so -> libpython2.7.so.1.0
-rwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4979591 Dec  6 16:09 libpython2.7.so.1.0
-rw-r--r--  3 user user  715160 Jan  3  2014 libreadline.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      16 Mar 21 13:46 libreadline.so -> libreadline.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      18 Mar 21 13:46 libreadline.so.6 -> libreadline.so.6.2
-rwxr-xr-x  3 user user  516418 Jan  3  2014 libreadline.so.6.2
-rw-rw-r--  2 user user 2977926 Jan 11 11:52 libsqlite3.a
-rwxrwxr-x  1 user user     984 Mar 21 13:46 libsqlite3.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      19 Mar 21 13:46 libsqlite3.so -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      19 Mar 21 13:46 libsqlite3.so.0 -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
-rwxrwxr-x  2 user user 2573507 Jan 11 11:52 libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
-rw-rw-r--  2 user user  613290 Mar  1 12:23 libssl.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      15 Mar 21 13:46 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.0
-rwxrwxr-x  2 user user  462887 Mar  1 12:23 libssl.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  3 user user 1154833 Mar 16  2015 libtcl8.5.so
-rwxr-xr-x  3 user user    3008 Mar 16  2015 libtclstub8.5.a
-rwxr-xr-x  3 user user 1257824 Mar 16  2015 libtk8.5.so
-rwxr-xr-x  3 user user    4446 Mar 16  2015 libtkstub8.5.a
-rw-r--r--  3 user user   98574 Jan  5  2015 libz.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      13 Mar 21 13:46 libz.so -> libz.so.1.2.8
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      13 Mar 21 13:46 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
-rwxr-xr-x  3 user user   91730 Jan  5  2015 libz.so.1.2.8
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user    4096 Mar 21 13:47 pkgconfig
drwxrwxr-x 26 user user   20480 Mar 21 13:49 python2.7
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user    4096 Mar 21 13:46 tcl8
drwxrwxr-x  6 user user    4096 Mar 21 13:46 tcl8.5
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    7356 Mar 21 13:46 tclConfig.sh
drwxrwxr-x  6 user user    4096 Mar 21 13:46 tk8.5
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    4299 Mar 21 13:46 tkConfig.sh
```

I have been cycling between the above `configure`, `sudo make`,`sudo makeinstall` and `sudo make distclean` but to no avail, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use conda with mod_wsgi and Apache. Use virtualenv. Conda's embedded Python install will be obscured from your Apache module AFAIK.